# Finding the parametrization for a sphere?

Tags: calculus

Find a parametrization for the circle centered around the origin, of radius 3 and contained in the xz-plane.

So from what I gathered you use the formula of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2= r^2$ to solve this problem. So you know what the radius is 3 yet how does one find xyz just from having the radius?

Comment: Do you know how to parameterize a circle in the plane case? If not, read here: http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html .

Comment: Read that page and make the obvious changes to pass from the $x-y$ plane to the $x-z$ plane in 3 dimensions.

Comment: So then you have (3cos(t), 0, 3sin(t)). Why is y zero?

Comment: Because $y=0$ for every point of the $x-z$ plane.

Answer (score 0):

A three dimensional surface in a two dimensional plane!? For a constant $y$ value we can define a small circle and the plane it is contained in.

We can use spherical coordinates. Choose a particular latitude, translate the circle with arbitrary displacements $(k_1,k_2,k_3)=0 .$ In the picture R=1 but you can set it $R=3$.

```
    k1 = 1; k2 = 2; k3 = 3; ph = .785; R = 1;
X = {(R  Cos[th]) Cos[ph] + k1, 
  R Sin[th] + k2, (R Cos[th]) Sin[ph] + k3}
ParametricPlot3D[X, {th, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2D problem !
Usually you write

$$\begin{cases}x=x_c+r\cos t,\\y=y_c+r\sin t.\end{cases}$$

Here it is

$$\begin{cases}x=x_c+r\cos t,\\z=z_c+r\sin t.\end{cases}$$

No sphere needed.